# Automatically reading data files containing special characters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, special-characters

I would like to import a data file in Matlab which is generated by an external software **automatically**.

This data file can occasionally contain special characters in its third column at random places. Therefore, I cannot simply utilize dlmread.

I'm figuring out how to import this file **automatically** in Matlab while inserting the data in a matrix. Also, identifying the special characters and replacing them by NaN is necessary.

Here is some sample data for you to get a better picture of the problem:

```
NACA0012    

Alfa =  25.00000 Re =        0.000 Xflap,Yflap =     0.000000    0.000000

   x      y     Cp  

1.00000  0.00126  0.53803
0.08399  0.04389 -7.27148
0.07278  0.04150 -8.16799
0.03346  0.02983-15.69087
0.02840  0.02771-18.03665
0.02399  0.02566-20.81862
0.00360  0.01041-95.28658
0.00238  0.00851*********
0.00141  0.00659*********
0.00070  0.00467*********
0.00025  0.00277*********
0.00003  0.00091*********
0.00003 -0.00091*********
0.00025 -0.00277-93.41611
0.00070 -0.00467-72.18787
0.00141 -0.00659-51.54605
0.00238 -0.00851-37.04853
```

Notice how the third column gets sort of 'stuck' onto the second column

Any help would be appreciated since I'm kinda stuck and don't know how to do it automatically. Maybe you guys can provide me with a piece of code to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Balraj

Comment: Are the columns always fixed width like that?

Comment: Check out `textscan`.

Comment: Yes, the columns always have a fixed width

Comment: @CST-Link Yeah I've checked the page. It seems promising but I really don't know how to implement it for this case unfortunately.  Thanks

Comment: @BalrajBoyal Oh, you mean you want code? Okay, I'm going to put an answer in 5 to 10 min.

Comment: How big is the data, it might be easier to parse each line as a whole string, and then select the numbers individually paired with if functions for detecting symbols, the problem is that if the data is big, this method becomes too time consuming.

Comment: @GameOfThrows The data set always consists out of 163 lines with three columns. The file size is just 5 Kb. Do you think its feasible to do it with your method?

Comment: @BalrajBoyal sure, it simply involves reading the data in as a whole string, and since all your data are of same length, simply pick out the index of the number readings and convert them to numbers.

Comment: @GameOfThrows How would you go and parse each line as a whole string and convert it back? num2str/str2num?

Comment: @BalrajBoyal I put an answer with code and corrected it. It works for the data that you posted.

Comment: @CST-Link Yes! it works. Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help. Where can I select this as an accepted answer

Comment: @BalrajBoyal Glad that I could help. There is a gray check-mark under the answer's poster, click it if you want to chose it as correct answer, and will turn green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `textscan` with 3 ideas in mind:

- One needs to skip the first lines;
- The `*` strings are to be treated as `NaN`s;
- In case of error close the file.

Hence the code (assuming that the example data are in the file `'u.txt'`):

```
try
        f = fopen('u.txt');
        m = textscan( f,                 ...
           '%f%f%f',        Inf,         ...
           'HeaderLines',   6,           ...
           'TreatAsEmpty',  '*********', ...
           'CollectOutput', 1            ...
        );
        fclose(f);

catch ME
        fclose('all');
end;
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the following error: Error: File: test2.m Line: 31 Column: 12
Unexpected MATLAB expression.

Comment: @BalrajBoyal There was a missing comma in the original posting, I corrected it. Please look again in the answer.

Comment: You can also use 'CollectOutput' flag instead of `cell2mat` after the fact.

Comment: @nkjt That is a better idea, indeed. Please, go ahead and edit the answer.